# Join two data frames in R based on closest timestamp

Tags: r, dataframe, timestamp, dplyr, posixct

Hi I have two tables (table1 and table2 below) and would like to join them based on the closest timestamp to form expected_output.  Some kind of solution involving dplyr would be great if possible, but not if it further complicates things.

```
table1 = 
structure(list(date = structure(c(1437051300, 1434773700, 1431457200
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), val1 = c(94L, 
33L, 53L)), .Names = c("date", "val1"), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame")

table2 = 
structure(list(date = structure(c(1430248288, 1435690482, 1434050843
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), val2 = c(67L, 
90L, 18L)), .Names = c("date", "val2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame")

expected_output = 
structure(list(date = structure(c(1437051300, 1434773700, 1431457200
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), val1 = c(94L,
33L, 53L), val2 = c(90L, 18L, 67L)), .Names = c("date", "val1", 
"val2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using rolling joins feature of `data.table` with `roll = "nearest"`:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
setDT(table1)[, val2 := setDT(table2)[table1, val2, on = "date", roll = "nearest"]]
```

Here, `val2` column is created by performing a *join* on the column `date` with `roll = "nearest"` option. For each row of `table1$date`, the closest matching row from `table2$date` is computed, and `val2` for corresponding row is extracted.

Comment: This is very helpful!  Any idea how to change from "nearest" to "most recent?"  I.e. keep time directional, and not merge to a row in the future?

Comment: @emudrak `roll=Inf` directional unlimited.   `roll=30` directional limit to staleness.  Use sign to control direction.

Answer (score 2):

This is liable to be slow, but...

```
d   <- function(x,y) abs(x-y) # define the distance function
idx <- sapply( table1$date, function(x) which.min( d(x,table2$date) )) # find matches

cbind(table1,table2[idx,-1,drop=FALSE])
#                  date val1 val2
# 2 2015-07-16 08:55:00   94   90
# 3 2015-06-20 00:15:00   33   18
# 1 2015-05-12 15:00:00   53   67
```

Another way of constructing `idx` is `max.col(-outer(table1$date, table2$date, d))`.