# Join two dataframes with several columns in R based on closest timestamp

Tags: r

This question has already been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818444/join-two-data-frames-in-r-based-on-closest-timestamp). However, the situation presented in the question and the proposed solution only work if the dataframes consist of just two variables, one of which is the timestamp.

I am surprised because this solution is not at all generalizable and it only tackles one very specific case.

So if we had a dataframe `df1` that looks like this:

```
Timestamp       Var1 Var2 ... Var850
01-01-20 10:47  7    8        5
01-01-20 11:50  6    4        3
```

And a dataframe `df2` that looks like this:

```
Timestamp       Var851 Var852 ... Var2992
01-01-20 10:55  4    1            1
01-01-20 12:08  3    4            6
```

How would we merge them based on the closest timestamp?

Comment: There isn't any reason why the answer you found wouldn't work in your case.

Comment: I think the answer there should work for your case as well. You just don't assign `val2 :=`. Provided your  `Timestamp` is of class  `POSIXct`. Did you try that? What output did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the world of `data.table`'s rolling joins

**sample data**

```
#or use
#    setDT(df1); setDT(df2)
#to convert existing data.frame df1 and df2 to data.table


library( data.table)
df1 <- data.table::fread("Timestamp       Var1 Var2 
01-01-20T10:47  7    8        
01-01-20T11:50  6    4")        

df2 <- data.table::fread("Timestamp       Var851 Var852
01-01-20T10:55  4    1
01-01-20T12:08  3    4")

#timestamps/dates have to be of posix- or date-class to be able 
#to roll-join them
df1[, Timestamp := as.POSIXct( Timestamp, format = "%d-%m-%yT%H:%M")]
df2[, Timestamp := as.POSIXct( Timestamp, format = "%d-%m-%yT%H:%M")]
```

**code**

```
df2[df1, roll = "nearest", on = .(Timestamp)]

#              Timestamp Var851 Var852 Var1 Var2
# 1: 2020-01-01 10:47:00      4      1    7    8
# 2: 2020-01-01 11:50:00      3      4    6    4
```